# GWT 2: а что дает inheritance виджетов их XML разметкам?

Tags: gwt, java

День добрый!

Объясните, пожалуйста, как XML layout виджета соотносится с XML layout виджета, от которого унаследован первый виджет?
Могу ли я использовать наследование для добавления общих элементов в разные экраны сайта? К примеру, унаследовался от виджета с меню - и появилось меню.

Или это так не работает и UIBinder про наследование ничего не знает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наследование виджета возможно, но для этого надо делать базовый виджет определённым образом. И XML-разметка базового виджета будет фиксированной, т.е. её нельзя переопределить (иначе, как вы себе это представляете?). В общем, это приведёт к определённым сложностям, в которые лучше не ввязываться без необходимости.

Я знаю, что повторяюсь, но используйте аггрегацию вместо наследования. Распилите свой интерфейс на типовые части и реализуйте их в виде виджетов, а потом добавляйте куда нужно. Так гораздо проще.